# Footer issue using CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am relatively new to CSS/Bootstrap, and I am trying to build my first responsive website.

I have a problem getting the footer to stick always to the bottom of the page or the content.

Could anyone offer any suggestions as to how I can get the footer to behave as mentioned above?  I have tried many sources online prior to posting this.

Comment: For Bootstrap3, there are 2 sticky footer examples on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples . View the source code on each of those and you'll be be off!

Answer (score 0):

just add following css

```
.container-fluid {
margin-bottom: 100px;
}

div#footer2 {
position: fixed;
width: 98%;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your footer code on desktop and ipad and works great - tried it on older Android samsung galaxy and the footer doesnt stay at the bottom, moves about vertically with the page - is this solvable?  thanks

Comment: can you share more details?

Comment: I'll try!  The footer as you suggested works great on all but the samsung galaxy phone I tried it on (android).  When the web page initially loads, the footer is stuck to the bottom of the viewport exactly as expected.  As soon as one scrolls the page up or down, the footer scrolls with the page as opposed to remaining all the time at the bottom - does that help?

Comment: I gues I got it, checkout the edited answer, all you need is to add `left:0`  and  `right:0` as well;

Comment: Many thanks for that - I have tried it but the footer on a Samsung still floats up and down with the page when scrolled - only happens on the Samsung, not any other device

Comment: I tried what you suggested - made no difference i'm afraid, however i have realised that the problem only affects older browsers older than a certain version - more recent ones do not have the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
div #footer_inner {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry not sure how you mean i should implement this as I dont have an element called footer_inner

Comment: ok so you have to use
footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use bootstrap's fixed class (there's also one for fixed top): [navbar-fixed-bottom](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom)